# Combined Vertical and horizontal orientation in XML table in Android App

Tags: android, xml, text, xmltable

I need to define Table which has a combined vertical and horizontal orientation.

I have tried a variety of XML definitions but have been unsuccessful so far.

My current code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.appname.td.MainActivity">
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tlGridTable" >
        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#FF9090" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/left_logo_dummy" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#FF9090" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:text="Name" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#FF9090" />
            <TextView
                android:rotation="270"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:text="29-May"
                android:background="#00ff22"/>
            <View
                android:rotation="0"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#FF9090" />
            <TextView
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:text="30-May"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:background="#00ff22" />
        </TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF9090" />

        <TableRow>
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#FF9090" />
            <TextView
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:background="#00ff22"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#ff9090" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:text="Uttam" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#FF9090" />
            <TextView
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:text="Y"
                android:background="#00ff22" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:background="#FF9090" />
            <TextView
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:text="N"
                android:background="#00ff22" />
        </TableRow>
        <View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#FF9090" />
</TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

I am experimenting only with the cell containing "29-May".  Since the second row and onwards each cell contains only one letter "Y" or "N", I would like the dates to be vertically aligned with the "2" in "29-May" at the bottom.

Whatever I try, I am unable to get a horizontal width of 18dp to that column and vertical height of 108dp.  If I change "layout_height" to 108dp, the entire cell becomes a square of 108dp x 108dp.

What I am doing wrong is quite trivial but I cannot for the world fathom what it is.

Can someone here help?

Comment: My goodness so many views with no use

Comment: The Views are to get horizontal and vertical lines in the manner of a tabular grid.

Don't want to digress from the main question - that of vertical orientation of the dates on the Date row while having horizontal orientations for the rows below it.

(Haven't investigated a better way for generating the grid so am not asking it here...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should use `ListView` with `Custom adapter` with below `layout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@color/BGo"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Day"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Activity Type"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Location Planned"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Remark"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Status"
                    android:textColor="@color/White" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:divider="@color/BGo"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```